# Gas counting. What is the difference between burnt gas and used gas?

Tags: nearprotocol

During the transaction execution we are counting how much we "gas burned" and how much "gas used". Why do we have to track these counters separately?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Gas used includes gas burnt, so `gas_used >= gas_burnt`, always;
- When any kind of fee is getting applied it counts towards both `gas_burnt` and `gas_used`;
- When contract performs a cross-contract call and attaches `X` amount of gas to this call, then `X` counts towards `gas_used` but not `gas_burnt`. This is the only source of discrepancy between `gas_used` and `gas_burnt`. If the smart contract fails before it finishes the execution then none of the cross-contract calls (or transactions created by the contract) get executed and the attached gas is refunded;
- Based on the previous bullet point when contract fails `gas_used - gas_burnt` is getting refunded back to the account, while `gas_burnt` is getting lost for good (because `gas_burnt` corresponds to the fees that actually costed some computation efforts to the validators).

Answer (score 1):

> while writing this answer, @MaksymZavershynskyi answered as well.
>
> his answer should be considered authoritative while mine is a guess.

taking a look at the source makes me think that

- `gas_used` is the cost of productive storage and compute (getting stuff done that doesn't fail)
- `gas_burnt` is the cost of unproductive transport, storage and compute (getting data from point A to point B, trying to execute a function but failing part way through execution or resulting in an error, etc)

---

here's a pile of snippets with links into the source code that left me with this impression

from `nearcore/runtime/runtime/src/lib.rs`

```rust
fn generate_refund_receipts(
    &self,
    receipt: &Receipt,
    action_receipt: &ActionReceipt,
    result: &mut ActionResult,
) -> Result<(), RuntimeError> {
    /// ... snip ...
    let gas_refund = if result.result.is_err() {
        safe_add_gas(prepaid_gas, exec_gas)? - result.gas_burnt
    } else {
        safe_add_gas(prepaid_gas, exec_gas)? - result.gas_used
    };
    /// ... snip ...
}
```

[source](https://github.com/nearprotocol/nearcore/blob/324b42e70166bb17fcf2435c2d75365c1f12ac24/runtime/runtime/src/lib.rs#L736-L740)

---

from `nearcore/runtime/runtime/src/actions.rs`

```rust
pub(crate) fn action_function_call(
    state_update: &mut TrieUpdate,
    apply_state: &ApplyState,
    account: &mut Option<Account>,
    receipt: &Receipt,
    action_receipt: &ActionReceipt,
    promise_results: &[PromiseResult],
    result: &mut ActionResult,
    account_id: &AccountId,
    function_call: &FunctionCallAction,
    action_hash: &CryptoHash,
    config: &RuntimeConfig,
    is_last_action: bool,
) -> Result<(), StorageError> {
    /// ... snip ...
    if let Some(outcome) = outcome {
        result.gas_burnt += outcome.burnt_gas;
        result.gas_burnt_for_function_call += outcome.burnt_gas;
        // Runtime in `generate_refund_receipts` takes care of using proper value for refunds.
        // It uses `gas_used` for success and `gas_burnt` for failures. So it's not an issue to
        // return a real `gas_used` instead of the `gas_burnt` into `ActionResult` for
        // `FunctionCall`s.
        result.gas_used += outcome.used_gas;
        result.logs.extend(outcome.logs.into_iter());
    }
    /// ... snip ...
}
```

[source](https://github.com/nearprotocol/nearcore/blob/324b42e70166bb17fcf2435c2d75365c1f12ac24/runtime/runtime/src/actions.rs#L184-L193)

---

from `nearcore/core/primitives/src/types.rs`

```rust
pub struct ChunkExtra {
  /// ... snip ...

  /// Actually how much gas were used.
  pub gas_used: Gas

/// ... snip ...
}
```

[source](https://github.com/nearprotocol/nearcore/blob/324b42e70166bb17fcf2435c2d75365c1f12ac24/core/primitives/src/types.rs)

---

from `nearcore/core/primitives/src/sharding.rs`

```rust
pub struct ShardChunkHeaderInner {
  /// ... snip ...

  /// Gas used in this chunk.
  pub gas_used: Gas,

  /// ... snip ...
}
```

[source](https://github.com/nearprotocol/nearcore/blob/324b42e70166bb17fcf2435c2d75365c1f12ac24/core/primitives/src/sharding.rs#L45-L46)

---

from `nearcore/runtime/runtime/src/config.rs`

```rust
/// ... snip ...

pub fn tx_cost(
    config: &RuntimeFeesConfig,
    transaction: &Transaction,
    gas_price: Balance,
    sender_is_receiver: bool,
) -> Result<(Gas, Gas, Balance), IntegerOverflowError> {
    let mut gas_burnt: Gas = config.action_receipt_creation_config.send_fee(sender_is_receiver);
    gas_burnt = safe_add_gas(
        gas_burnt,
        total_send_fees(&config, sender_is_receiver, &transaction.actions)?,
    )?;
    let mut gas_used = safe_add_gas(gas_burnt, config.action_receipt_creation_config.exec_fee())?;
    gas_used = safe_add_gas(gas_used, total_exec_fees(&config, &transaction.actions)?)?;
    gas_used = safe_add_gas(gas_used, total_prepaid_gas(&transaction.actions)?)?;
    let mut total_cost = safe_gas_to_balance(gas_price, gas_used)?;
    total_cost = safe_add_balance(total_cost, total_deposit(&transaction.actions)?)?;
    Ok((gas_burnt, gas_used, total_cost))
}
/// ... snip ...


/// Total sum of gas that would need to be burnt before we start executing the given actions.
pub fn total_exec_fees(
    config: &RuntimeFeesConfig,
    actions: &[Action],
) -> Result<Gas, IntegerOverflowError> {
  /// ... snip ...
}

/// Get the total sum of deposits for given actions.
pub fn total_deposit(
    actions: &[Action]
) -> Result<Balance, IntegerOverflowError> {
  /// ... snip ...
}

/// Get the total sum of prepaid gas for given actions.
pub fn total_prepaid_gas(
    actions: &[Action]
) -> Result<Gas, IntegerOverflowError> {
  /// ... snip ...
}
```

[source](https://github.com/nearprotocol/nearcore/blob/324b42e70166bb17fcf2435c2d75365c1f12ac24/runtime/runtime/src/config.rs#L152-L169)